# On DSE 5.0.5 (Cassandra 3.0.11) which settings would reduce read latencies with constant writes in the background?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, cassandra

We have a 5 node DSE cassandra cluster and an application whose job is to write asynchronously to keyspace A (which is based on a HDD), and read synchronously from keyspace B (which is on an SSD). Reads from table

Additional info:

- The table on A is using TWCS with 48h windows, while the table on keyspace B is using LCS with default settings
- Spark jobs partition reads in chunks of 20h at most
- Both tables are using TDE with AES256 keys and 1KB chunks
- Azul Zing is being used as the JVM with default settings apart from heap sizing and GC logging

With this scenario alone the read latencies from keyspace B are fine throughout the day, but everyday we have a spark job that will read from keyspace A and write to B. The moment the spark executors "attack" keyspace A, read latencies from keyspace B suffer a bit (99th percentil goes from 8-12ms to 130ms for a few seconds).

My question is, which cassandra.yaml properties would likely help the most on reducing the read latencies on keyspace B just for this moment the spark job starts? I've been trying different memtable/commitlog settings, but haven't been able to lower the read latency to acceptable levels

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to generalize without knowing why your latency hurts, if we could we’d bake those defaults into the database

However, I’ll try to guess

- Throttle down concurrent reads so there are fewer concurrent requests - this will trade throughout for more consistent performance
- if your disk is busy, consider smaller compression chunk sizes
- if you’re seeing GC pauses, consider tuning your jvm - the Cassandra-8150 jira has some good suggestions
- if your sstables-per-read is more than a few, reconsider your data model to keep your partitions from spanning multiple TWCS windows
- make sure your key cache is enabled. If you can spare the heap, raise it, it may help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Jeff, a few comments (how do I insert a newline in here?): I would want to throttle reads to keyspace A, but reads on B cannot be throttled as they are on the critical path - is it possible to do this on a keyspace/table basis? ; chunks are 1KB with AES256 TDE, I'll try to reduce them ; We are using Azul Zing as the JVM, no major pauses observed (added to the post) ; windows are 48h, each partition takes at most 20h ; I'll investigate the key cache :)

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with DSE to know if your 1K AES chunks correspond to reading 1K off the disk, or if it's still using 64k buffers underneath. You could ask DS support for confirmation. I wouldn't bother going smaller than 1K. You can not throttle reads per keyspace/table, the thread pool is per-server. Zing should surely be better by default than any tunings you see in CASSANDRA-8150. Next step, I imagine, is to try to figure out why you're slipping. OS inspection and JVM profiling (for example, heap maps to see where you're spending most of your time) may be the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff's answer should be your starting point but if that doesn't solve it, consider changing your spark job to off-peak time. Keep in mind that LCS is optimized for read-heavy tables, but from the moment that spark starts to "migrate" the data, that table using LCS, will for some time (until the spark job finishes) become a write-heavy table. This would be an anti-pattern for LCS utilization. I can't know for sure without looking into servers details, but I would say that due to the sheer number of SSTables that are created during the spark job, LCS is not able to keep up with the compaction to maintain the standard read latency.

If you can't schedule the spark job at an off-peak time, then you should consider changing the compaction strategy in the keyspace B to STCS.

Comment: We are already off-peak :) Regarding LCS, I agree that in the moment the Spark jobs start writing it becomes a write-heavy table and I can see the compactor trying to keep up.. But if 95% of the day the table is meant solely for random reads I would like to keep LCS and avoid STCS :\